# VueJS V-bind:sync="{object}" -- watching data emitted from child in parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am writing an app in which I have a parent component that passes an Object, `this.form` to a child form component via `v-bind:sync="form"`, with the child form emitting values for each of the keys of the parent on @input.

I want to watch the value of `this.form` in the parent, but it seems the object on the parent is not reactive in the case of v-bind:sync, even though on a submit action in the parent I submit `this.form` with all of the emitted values from the child.

Code example
Parent:

```
<ParentComponent>

  <ChildComponent v-bind:sync="form"/>

  {{form}} <--- this doesn't update after child component emits

   <button @click="submit"> submit actions here have access to updated this.form... </button>
</ParentComponent>

...

data() {
  return {
      form: { ...some object keys}
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you "emitting values for each of the keys of the parent on @input"?

Comment: Hi Tony, here are the Vue docs re: component $emit functions/events, you use $emit to pass values from child to parent: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: I'm aware of `$emit`. I was actually asking for the exact code you were using to pass values to the parent, as the problem could've been in that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `deep` in watcher to watch object properties change.

Something like

```
  watch: {
    form: {
      handler() {
        console.log('form change')
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
```

As in [document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options)

> To also detect nested value changes inside Objects, you need to pass
> in deep: true in the options argument. Note that you don’t need to do
> so to listen for Array mutations.

I created a [demo here](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/zYxrBGX)